# css for font works when testing in sandbox, but won't work when applied to webpage

Tags: html, css

so I'm currently trying to get this css font thing to work, and I have no idea why it isn't. So here's my page :

https://web.njit.edu/~kl297/webtest/home.html

For some reason the text is in arial. If you copy and paste the exact code thats written on the page into cssdesk, the css works :

http://www.cssdesk.com/cMrtH

Does anyone know what's going on???

Comment: Don't remove the original question, as it won't help other users who may find this question. It is the purpuse of questions and anwers  to be as quickly accessible as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`https`** in your import link, like:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Geo&subset=latin);
```

instead of

`@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Geo&subset=latin);`

> This is because your page is served using `https` but the font you are requesting was loaded over insecure URL (i.e. `http`). Therefore you need to to use `https` in your import URL inside the style tag.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you DaaAA MaNNN

Comment: Thanks @kevinle . Please accept this answer if this helped you out.